# Cookie doesn't change when reset to expire in past/present

Tags: php, cookies

I'm struggling over an hour on how to delete cookies. I found out that to delete a cookie, its value must be set to past, so it expires. However if I try with time()-something or even time() nothing is done to cookie. However setting expiration time to time()+1 works. But I'd like to have the cookie deleted immediately. Not after 1 second. 
So this works:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['rememberme'])) setcookie('rememberme', 'del',  time()+1, '/', 'localhost');
```

This doesn't do anything to the cookie, leaving it as it was before logout:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['rememberme'])) setcookie('rememberme', 'del',  time()-1, '/', 'localhost');
```

Comment: `time()-1` is silly. Use `time()-1000000`. Or better yet, `strtotime('1 month ago')`. Much more readable.

Comment: It will only be deleted if  you refresh the page. Also, be sure the cookie path is thesame.

Comment: Cookie path is the same. It doesn't matter whether I refresh the page or not. The cookie is still there with it's old value and old expiration date (that is one year ahead).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is my browser's fault. If expiration time is set to past it displays the old cookie as it was before log out, however my script acts like this cookie doesn't exist. The browser is Iceweasel (Firefox on Debian).